# Pass data to lazy loaded module and make available to services without going through components

Tags: angular

I have a lazy loaded module I need to pass some config data into.

I know you cannot use forRoot for lazy loaded modules.

I have tried passing data in the route, which works, but as far as I know the only way to fetch it in the lazy loaded module is from the ngOnInit method of the root component. The problem is that I need this data in an API service that is instantiated and used before the root component of the lazy loaded module is initialised, so by the time ngOnInit is called, it is too late. For example, the API service is called from resolvers, which are executed before the component is initialised.

Is there a way of getting the data form the route from a service in the lazy loaded module or passing it some other way? I would like this module to be standalone so I cannot inject application-level services into it. The data needs to be passed in dynamically.

What I have tried:

Pass data into the lazy loaded module from the root routing module

//app/app-routing.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
   {
        path: 'feature',
        loadChildren: 'feature#featureModule',
        data: {
            test: 'someData'
        }
    },
]
```

In the lazy loaded module, I can fetch the data from the root component

// feature/root.component.ts

```
export class FeatureRootComponent {

    constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              ) {

        this.activatedRoute.data.pipe(
            take(1)
        ).subscribe(data => {
           console.log(data.test); // works fine
        });

}
```

Comment: You can pass data as route params inside the Lazy Loading module component Routes Config

Comment: Sorry I would need a bit more detail to understand what you mean. Thanks,

Comment: This is a great question, why is no one interested?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what Suresh was saying is that you can pass an object in your routing module.
For example:

```
{
    path: 'user',
    loadChildren: 'src/to/lazy-loaded-module/user.module#UserModule',
    data: {
        breadcrumbLabel: 'User Data',
        someOtherData: true,
        extraInfo: 'xyz'
    },
    resolve: {
        resolveService: ExamplaryResolver
    }

}
```

and reference it in children components by using ActivatedRoute and it's data property or in ExamplaryResolver by using ActivatedRouteSnapshot

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {

    do some stuff here with route.data
    and return

}
```

Comment: I like this answer, but struggling on how to define the ExamplaryResolver. Would you mind pasting some more example code?